# T-SQL and decision making constructs

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Please help me with the syntax of this query. It doesn't compile. It says there's a syntax error near the keyword END.

Obviously, I've got these BEGINs and ENDS mixed up.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I am not sure of the syntax of these `BEGIN`S and `END`s.

Please don't mind the condition `1 = 0`. That's something that will be replaced with a proper predicate later.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StringCategory WHERE ResourceKeyId = 18134 AND CategoryId = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE StringCategory
        SET CategoryId = 0
        WHERE ResourceKeyId = 18134
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF 1 = 0
            BEGIN
            DELETE FROM StringCategory WHERE ResourceKeyId = 18134
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO StringCategory
            VALUES(18134, 0)
            END
    END
END
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question. I had the question in the title earlier and then I changed the title just before hitting the Save button.

Comment: even if syntax was correct, your query makes very little functional sense, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last END is an extra.  You can think of the BEGINs and ENDs like { and } in C# for the IF constructs (They serve to mark the beginning and end of the block to be executed in the IF/ELSE statement).

Comment: Thank you. It's difficult to get this correct for someone like me who has not been very regular practicing SQL. Another 10 minutes before I can mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler way to do what you appear to be attempting.

```
  insert into StringCategory
  (ResourceKey, CategoryId)
  select 18134, 0
  where not exists (
  SELECT * 
  FROM StringCategory 
  WHERE ResourceKeyId = 18134 
  AND CategoryId = 0)
```